# read variable from dropdown function in javascript

Tags: alert, dropdown

i am using this dropdown in html file:

```
<select id="read-type"  onchange="checkrt()">                           
                    <option value="1">2word</option>                    
                    <option value="2">3word</option>
                    <option value="3">line</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
```

and read it by:

```
var dro = document.getElementById("read-type");
var readtype = dro.options[dro.selectedIndex].value;
```

but this code can't read "onchange" or i don't now how?, so i change the code to:

```
$(function checkrt(){
    $('#read-type').on('change', function(){        
        window.readtype = $(this).val();
        alert(readtype);
    });
})
```

the last code work good with "alert", but i can't read the the variable "readtype" in the next function by:

```
    Function delta(text){
if (readtype == 1)
```

this give me msg (un define readtype)?, please what th problem.

note: the code can get readtype if i clicked on "refresh" button in the browser after i change the selected item in dropdown.

- the code in app.js not in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a named function to contain the `onchange` trigger. To get access to the value, you'll have to pass `readtype` into your next function.

Change your code to this:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#read-type').on('change', function(){        
        var readtype = $(this).val();
        nextFunction(readtype);
    });

    function nextFunction(readtype){
        if (readtype == 1) {
            alert(readtype);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="read-type">
    <option value="1">2word</option>
    <option value="2">3word</option>
    <option value="3">line</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, but my 2nd function out of the first function, sorry not work with me.